# Should I ignore or reply an external colleague insisting in sharing methods in potentially COI project?

Tags: etiquette, email, collaboration, conflict-of-interest

I (scientist X working at lab A) have received several e-mails from one specific colleague (scientist Y working at lab B) regarding engaging in some specific project led by Y. Some of the ideas I could share are based on recent papers and one specific major work of mine, informally discussed between labs A and B. In general, both labs actively collaborate on some other projects.

I have declined both in-person and also via e-mail for this specific collaboration due to a lack of alignment/priorities. My general assessment is that sharing more knowledge minimizes the efforts and results of my own project. However, scientist Y has written multiple follow-up e-mails to me i) cc’ing multiple supervisors, which I consider unnecessary, and ii) asking for multiple technical/sharing points that I have already declined.

I consider the behavior from Y a bit off. Professionally, I consider it sufficient to accept/decline collaborations and ignore additional points directed to a single person, especially in group e-mails, after declining. I also cannot reveal additional know-how through those, due to COI. As an academic, I reply to most e-mails and share knowledge, but in this case, it is a bit of a predatory request.

Comment: Have you discussed the options with your direct supervisor? If yes, and they are supportive of your position, and agree to the following, feel free to either ignore further emails, or reply to one cc'ing your supervisor and deferring further discussion to them.

Comment: I don't understand the conflict of interest angle here, can you explain?

Comment: @JonCuster My supervisor fully aligns with me and is supportive of my position.

Comment: @Stierlitz - OK, then I as the supervisor would contact Y's direct supervisor and request that there be no further emails on the topic. My job is to protect my people, and attempts at bullying by others is just not OK.

Comment: @BryanKrause regarding COI, Y can benefit from me sharing specific ideas/software, but I have to invest time in generating results and know-how of my features with them. This is a sub-packaging of the current academic release/licensing strategy that I have planned for my project.

Comment: @Stierlitz A "conflict of interest" is when one person has different interests that conflict, especially a personal benefit versus some ethical duty; for example, if your child is a student in your class, there is a conflict between wanting your child to do well and a duty to assess all students fairly. If you have a financial interest in a certain experimental result and work for a university, there is a conflict between your financial gains and your academic duty to represent research results accurately and without bias. Not a conflict between people.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks. I am using the COI concept to define a conflict between two in-parallel competing projects, run independently by labs A and B, and in which lab members cannot officially work for both projects at the same time due to contract and lab assignment. I think the COI concept fits or there is a better term for it?

Comment: @Stierlitz I would only describe it as a conflict of interest if someone has an interest separately in each project. Otherwise, you just have some interpersonal conflicts. Overall, this arrangement seems strange to me - are you developing for some outside commercial interest? Normally there is no legal/official boundary between academic labs with different funding sources collaborating on the same projects. There may be practical ones surrounding making sure people get credit for work they do and avoiding situation where overlap makes one person's project moot.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is, go have a quiet talk with your supervisor. Be sure to be in a calm mood when you do. Do the "go to your happy place" thing before. Explain the situation and ask for help.

I feel for you on the COI aspects. Congrats on being aware of it. In this office we are required to re-take the COI training at least once per year. Tedious! There are many aspects to it that are not instantly obvious until somebody points them out. The natural thing for an academic of wanting to talk about the work can turn around and bite you hard if there are paying clients involved. Or if there is intellectual property that has a monetary value. Even different departments of the same client may not be entitled to unrestricted access to the information.

Also, the aspect that this person is continuing to press and even escalating, that is worrisome. If they wanted to escalate after you said "no" then the thing they should have done is gone through the "command chain." They should have asked the "brass" in their lab to contact the corresponding people in your lab. They should not have continued to badger you.

Try not to make enemies. Try not to burn bridges. Either in your lab or the other lab. It is conceivable there is a way for the two labs to collaborate to everybody's benefit. It just may require some careful negotiation.

On the other hand, don't let yourself get crowded into violating COI. Or other ethical concerns. That can be really hard on your prospects.